# How can I find which part of my program has circular dependency?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependencies, circular-dependency

I have a lot of circular dependency errors in the angular project and unfortunately, my project doesn't run correctly.

How can I find which part of my program has circular dependency?

```
Warning: Circular dependency detected:
   src\app\@core\data\services\project-management\project\project-target.service.ts -> 
   src\app\@core\data\services\shared\data.service.ts -> src\app\auth\security.service.ts -> 
   src\app\@core\data\services\project-management\index.ts -> 
   src\app\@core\data\services\project-management\project\project-target.service.ts
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means classes or modules are referencing each other. While you should aim to avoid this, it's not always possible.

For example, a circular dependency is when `A` is directly referencing B and vice versa: `A -> B -> A`, or indirectly `A -> B -> C -> A`.

If possible, you should break this chain of dependency. Maybe the modules in `B` can be moved into `A` or maybe the dependencies that both `A` and `B` reference can be moved to `C`.

In your case, you can see both of direct and indirect circular referencing.

Do I understand it correctly, that your index.ts is being referenced by other modules? If so, that should not happen. `index.ts` is the base file of the project and shouldn't be referenced by anything else in the `src` folder.